# Should I store unordered values from a series with large holes in a sparse Vec or HashMap in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust, hashmap

I have a file that contains millions of rows of data. Each row has a unique id and the id series are many times not in order, and can contain holes. `1, 2, 10, 6, 3, 18` for example.

I want to be able to quickly access the rows by ID, so I'm thinking storing them in a `HashMap` could be a viable solution, but this feels like overkill when they could be stored in a `Vec`.

Is storing them in a `Vec` a good solution when the holes in the series can get pretty large (`1, 2, 3, 1000000, 1000001...` and so on)? I will be discarding a lot of rows. Should use some kind of `HashMap`?

Comment: why do you need to only work with index from your data ?

Comment: There are other options, such as `BTreeMap<Id, T>`, or sorted `Vec<(Id, T)>`, both of which have `O(log n)` retrieval.

Comment: What do your benchmarks and profiler say when you try both with your data?

Comment: The problem with "architecture questions" like this one is that in order to answer them, we need to know a lot about your priorities, data access patterns, and perhaps even hardware information. Either answer, or neither, could be correct -- what is more important, compactness or speed? Speed of random access or of iteration? Is the ordering of IDs important? Etc.

Comment: (Another option that comes to mind is to use a `Vec<T>` and use a translation table to turn the row IDs into `usize`s for indexing; this has the advantage that when you've built the whole `Vec`, if you do it carefully, you can then drop the translation table and manipulate the structure only using your own internal IDs. Of course this only makes sense if the external row IDs are not important.)

Answer (score 1):

[HashMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) will definitely work well. Depending on the data, a sparse Vec might work even better, might work poorly, or might fail entirely. The safest and simplest option is to use the HashMap and revisit the question if you discover you need to optimise this specific function (which you probably won't).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the HashMap approach first then. Just a thought though. Intuitively it feels a bit wasteful to hash a already unique number. Wouldn't it -at least in theory- be possible to implement some sort of hashmap for numbers that doesn't need to be hashed?

Comment: Yes it's possible (see [`g_direct_hash`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.54/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-direct-hash) in GLib for example). It may not be a good idea though: most hash table implementations rely on the assumption that hashes are reasonably random, which your numbers almost certainly won't be…

Comment: You could also try a `BTreeMap` depending on the exact use case